# I cant run sudo

Tags: xubuntu, execute-command

On all distributions of ubuntu and linux that I use don't let me type in the password to use sudo what do I do what happens is that when I try to use the sudo command I cant type the password.

Comment: Why can't you type? Someone doesn't let you? Just do it, don't be scared.

Comment: What have you tried, and what happend ?

Comment: Linux hides all symbols for sudo password.  You only know you have typed the right password when not asked for password again and command works.  Make sure caps lock is off, unless password is all caps.

Answer (score 0):

Peheaps you need to type

`su`

command. Some distros use su instead of sudo. I preffer the former.

Comment: OP won't be able to type a password there as well :-)